# Quantum oscillator, position mean value problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

A quantum harmonic oscillator of mass $m$ and frequency $\omega$ is at time $t=0$ in the state:
$$
\left|\psi(t)\right> = \sum_{n=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left|n\right>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Delta N +1}},
$$
where $\left|n\right>$ is the $n$-th eigenket of the number operator and $N\gg\Delta N \gg1$. Show that at time $t>0$:
$$
\left<\psi(t)\right|\hat{q}\left|\psi(t)\right> \simeq \sqrt{\frac{2 \hbar N}{m \omega}}\sin \omega t.
$$
My try, as follows.

First we write the time dependent ket, using the time evolution operator:
$$
\left|\psi(t)\right> = e^{-i\hat{H}t/\hbar}\left|\psi(0)\right> = 
\sum_{n=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left|n\right>e^{-i\omega t(1+n/2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Delta N +1}}. 
$$
Then we write the expectation value:
$$
\left<\psi(t)\right|\hat{q}\left|\psi(t)\right> = 
\left(\sum_{n'=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left<n'\right|e^{+i\omega t(1+n'/2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Delta N +1}}\right)\hat{q}\left(\sum_{n=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left|n\right>e^{-i\omega t(1+n/2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Delta N +1}}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sum_{n, n'=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}e^{i\omega t(n'-n)}\left<n'\right|\hat{q}\left|n\right>.
$$
Now, using the creation $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and annihilation $\hat{a}$ operators we have:
$$
\hat{q} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\hat{a}+\hat{a}^\dagger),
$$
therefore:
$$
\left<n'\right|\hat{q}\left|n\right> =\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\left( \left<n'\right|\hat{a}\left|n\right> + \left<n'\right|\hat{a}^\dagger\left|n\right>\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\left(\delta_{n', n-1}\sqrt{n}+\delta_{n',n+1}\sqrt{n+1}\right).
$$
Substituting back into our expression yields:
$$
\frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\sum_{n, n'=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}e^{i\omega t(n'-n)}\left(\delta_{n', n-1}\sqrt{n}+\delta_{n',n+1}\sqrt{n+1}\right) = \\
\frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\sum_{n=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left(e^{-i\omega t}\sqrt{n}+e^{i\omega t}\sqrt{n+1}\right)=f(t).
$$
By bringing the derivative under the sum we see that:
$$
\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}+\omega^2f(t)=0
$$
which means: $f(t) = A \cos \omega t + B \sin \omega t.$
All we have to do now is finding the coefficients. We know that:
$$
f(0) = A = \frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\sum_{n=N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)\simeq\\ \frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} \int_{N-\Delta N}^{N+\Delta N} dn \left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2\Delta N+1}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} 2\sqrt{N}\left(2\Delta N +\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right),
$$
where in the last passage we did the trivial integration and then used a first order Taylor expansion. Similarly, B yields zero at first order in $\Delta N /N$.
So we have:
$$
\left<\psi(t)\right|\hat{q}\left|\psi(t)\right> \simeq \sqrt{\frac{2 \hbar N}{m \omega}}\cos \omega t \frac{2\Delta N +1/2 - 1/2}{2\Delta N +1/2 + 1/2}
$$
which is not quite what I was supposed to find.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fraction in your result is very close to one since $\Delta N \gg 1$ and that fraction is just $\Delta N / (\Delta N + 1)$. You still have a cosine, but that is jsut a time-shifted sine, so I think you're done!

Comment: I'm not thoroughly convinced. Indeed the two constants are similar, and their ratio is almost one, but since this is just an exercise, the teacher would have put just a $2\Delta N$ normalisation constant I guess. What troubles me most is exactly the cosine: sine and cosine only differ by a phase, but we are not talking about wave functions here, rather we are inspecting average values, which should be univocally determined by the initial setup...

Comment: Setting things like your fraction $x/(x+1) = 1$ for large $x$ is a standard simplification in physics (and very well justified mathematically). For the $\sin$ argument: the time at which you start measuring is arbitrary. You could have started measuring at $t' = t - 2\pi / \omega$, turning a $\cos\omega t' \mapsto \sin\omega t$.